# Reverse order of rows of data.frame in R

Tags: r

I would like to reverse order of rows of data.frame in R gently way, but `rev` reverse the order of columns transposition fails because I deal with `data.frame`, not `matrix` class object. Is there alternative to writing :

`dataset <- dataset[nrow(dataset):1,]`

?

`base` based sulution is prefered

this question is different because its heavy emphasize coding style

Comment: Whats wrong with the solution you have? I think that will be the simplest approach.

Comment: @Keith Hughitt it uses `nrow()` and `[` its ugly for me, `dataset <- rev(dataset)` looks realy good but does not work